# In a select element, how do I designate the initially selected option from my model in Elm?

Tags: elm

Let's say I have a select element to choose a person, and I want to have a certain person, say with id = 3, to be initially selected. How do I pass this id down into my options, and then set the selected attribute to True in that options?

Some sample code:

```
personSelect : List Person -> String -> Html Msg
personSelect : personList selectedId =
    div []
        [ select [] (List.map personOption personList) ]


personOption : Person -> Html Msg
personOption : person = 
    option [ value (toString person.id) ] [ text person.name ]
```

Specifically, how do I get "selectedId" passed to "personOption"? Can I even do this using List.map?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Provide `selectedId` as an argument to `personOption` and exploit that you can partially apply functions in Elm. That is, when you give a function some but not all of the arguments that it needs, you get back a function waiting for the remaining arguments.

First, add `selectedId` to `personOptions` and render the option as selected if it matches.

```
personOption : String -> Person -> Html Msg
personOption selectedId person = 
  option 
    [ selected (selectedId == person.id)
    , value (toString person.id)
    ]
    [ text person.name ]
```

Then partially apply `personOption` by giving it its first argument *before* passing it on to `map`:

```
personSelect : List Person -> String -> Html Msg
personSelect personList selectedId =
  div []
    [ select [] 
        (List.map (personOption selectedId) personList) 
        -- personOption selectedId : String -> Html Msg
     ]
```